# count of comma separated values in column mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ifnull(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(varchar SEPARATOR ',')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(varchar SEPARATOR ','), ',', '')) + 1,0) AS total    
FROM tablename    
WHERE date(date and time)=curdate()
```

varchar this column contain comma separated values with this I am getting count of comma separated values in column exactly but not working for large data.

is there any solution to get count without length problem

Comment: You're not really asking any question here. Also, your explanation of the problem is unclear to me.

Comment: It would be much better to actually do "SELECT count(varchar) AS total ..."

Comment: What type of coma? Toxic, metabolic, neurologic or induced?

Comment: If i use count on  comma separated values of column  it returns number of rows only

Comment: Your varchar column already contains multiple values per row? You did not specify such thing..

Comment: In my question i mentioned that varchar contain multiple values that are separated by comma , I Want count of that

Comment: @Surekha yes, sorry, I misinterpreted that :( - well, best advice I can give you is to not do that - it is often called [list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.cz/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html) - other than that, as Peter pointed out, you actually do not ask the question - you do not specify what "length problem" you have, do "large data" give error, too big a number, too small?

Comment: okay for suppose i have 100 rows on compared date in query,So it must give count more than 100 because of each row may contain 1 or two values with comma separated    **I want count of that so I tried this query ** But giving accurate answer  up to 88 --I want total count--

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting limit of [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) - that means that anything longer than (by default) 1024 chars will be truncated so you don't get all results.

Possible solution is counting items per row and summing rows counts.

```
SELECT SUM(ifnull(LENGTH(varchar) - LENGTH(REPLACE(varchar, ',', '')) + 1,0)) AS total    
FROM tablename    
WHERE date(date and time)=curdate()
```

That way you don't need to think about that limit at all.

Just raising group_concat_max_len is not really a viable solution because you will only hit it later.

The real solution is to get rid of comma separated lists and introduce another table where each item will be separate row. That way most counts and similar operations are simpler.